# how to Convert double's exponetial form to normal decimal form

Tags: java

All Experts
I am doing some logical stuff in my program with an variable of type double.
everything is Ok when the value of type double parameter is  less then 1,00,00,000.
But when the value of it becomes > one Crores it is automatically converted in to an exponetial form and i got an exception .

For Example

> Value 10010001.25 becomes
>   1.001000125E7

I want the value is in normal form .

Any help ??

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: How are you printing this value? It's all about the way your format the double value.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the exception for more information to answer?

Comment: What is 10,00,00,000? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d))`.

Here is a comparison of some alternatives:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 10010001.125;

        // 10010001.125000 (lots of trailing zeroes)
        System.out.printf("%f%n", d);


        // 10010001.13 (perhaps not what you want)
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);


        // 10010001.12 (not accurate in my opinion)
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(d));


        // 10010001.125 (all relevant digits, and no trailing zeroes)
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: using new BigDecimal(d) happens to work in this case provided the faction is a sum of powers of 1/2 e.g. 1/8 in your case.  If you use 0.1 for example you won't get what you expect. ;)

Comment: yes , good point by Peter Lawrey . i suggest to use 1250.2 as a value of d and if we do new BigDecimal(d) it is giving the value  1250.09999999999990905052982270717620849609375. what should i do ?

Comment: If you want to represent the value 1250.2 in the computer, you should use `BigDecimal`, and not `double`. You could for instance do `d = new BigDecimal("1250.2");`

Answer (score 1):

The `double` is a binary format.  The two formats you see are different ways of converting a double into a String. You can try DecimalFormat to convert a number into a decimal formatted String.

However you might find this simpler

```
double d = 10010001.25;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```

prints

```
10010001.25
```

EDIT:

```
System.out.printf("%,.2f%n", d);
```

prints

```
10,010,001.25
```

Comment: Note that this approach strips out any thousandths though.

Comment: @aioobe, as per the OP's example. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat`

```
        double d = 10010001.25;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.print(df.format(d));
```